# How to change CouchDB version for Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to run the BYFN first network sample for Hyperledger Fabric v1.4. I am able to start the network by giving command "sh byfn.sh -m up" (after setting up binaries and pre-requisites of course). The test runs well and the chaincode is started on peers and an output is produced as well.

But when I try to start the same network with the command "sh byfn.sh -s couchdb", the network starts, but there is an error when the peer joins the channel. I have asked about this issue in a separate post here, where you can find the logs -  [rpc error - Proposal failed when peer joins channel in Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183574/rpc-error-proposal-failed-when-peer-joins-channel-in-fabric?noredirect=1#comment106469584_60183574)

There seems to be problem with couchDB version as the logs say,

```
> Error during CouchDB
> > CreateDatabaseIfNotExist() for dbName: mychannel_  error: json:
> > cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type
> > int panic: Error during commit to txmgr:json: cannot unmarshal string
> > into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type int
```

Now I guess the couchDb version for fabric v1.4 is v2.3 , how do I use a different version or a different image of couchdb so that I can check for the same? I have been through this issue for a while and not able to find a solution.

Comment: looks like you need this fix in fabric 2.0 to use any version: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/349afce600737a4fde7bf101c0752d98f5d3e8b2 otherwise you would need to use couch 2.2-, probably by editing the docker configurations byfn.sh relies on.

Comment: any idea where exactly i need to add the version configuration?